# Meaning of "which we have"

Tags: grammar

What does *which we have* mean here?

> In the end, will you be looking over your shoulder for the rest of your life wondering if your time is up? The short answer is yes. The long answer is definitely yes. The truth is, there’s a bull’s-eye on your back, and committing to this new life is your best shot at staying alive. And while you may never be able to remove that bull’s-eye, you can certainly cover it up with a Buzz Lightyear spacesuit and jetpack. **Which we totally have.**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an elision of 'Which we totally have done.' (I'd put 'Which _we_ have done. Emphatically.') Care needs to be taken when eliding verb-forms, and while this example does it for effect, it obviously can lead to confusion (your query, and see mplungjan's answer). It's usually safer to elide a verb after the auxiliary 'be' than 'have', because 'have' is commonly used as a main verb also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edwin has a point, I seem to have overlooked the significance of "you can (generic "one can") cover it up" so the sentence gets a slightly different meaning (implicit *done* added)

> One can cover it up with a Buzz Lightyear spacesuit and jetpack and we certainly have done just that.

viz

> ***Children's Disney Bullet Proof Backpacks:***
>   These Disney childrens’ backpacks have been outfitted with a RynoHide carbon nanotube armor insert, the same material used in anti-ballistic vests, making them miniature bulletproof backpacks to be used as shields when necessary. This process is performed by a variety of American companies, however Disney no longer permits it with their brand.

---

In other uses, totally can make a sentence sarcastic:

> Look that house costs a million
>   Which I *totally* have!

means I of course do not have a million.

or just emphasise agreement, but to me it sounds a little surfer dude-ish

> Dude, let's go hang out with the dudettes
>   Totally!

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with 'have' being interpreted as 'possess' here. Which would necessitate 'totally' being interpreted as 'certainly' as you say - but for which I can find no justification in dictionaries.

Comment: I agree, please see update @EdwinAshworth

Comment: I see you've also updated _bull’s-eye_ to _bulls eye_, in line with the modern move involving 'dropping apostrophes from constructions showing associative rather than true possessive relationships'. This particular example is the only thing that saddens me about the move - there aren't that many words (? strings?) containing both an apostrophe and a hyphen.

Comment: Oops. That is because I was on my phone, corrected

Comment: My immediate understanding would be that ‘have’ is indeed possessive here: “… Buzz Lightyear spacesuit and jet pack, and we totally have those things (available for you)”, using the spacesuit and jet pack as metaphors for the techniques and aids they can offer people in the witness protection programme to help remove the bull’s-eye. On second reading, though, I do realise that the sentence is quite ambiguous.

Comment: Can whoever voted this down take another look?

Comment: I wasn't implying that _bulls eye_ is incorrect. Merely saying that I'm sorry to see _bull's-eye_ going.